# Replacing strings with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

A particular regular expression is bugging me right now. I simply want to replace the **range=100** in a string like

```
var string = '...commonstringblabla<b>&range=100&</b>stringandsoon...';
```

with

```
...commonstringblabla<b>&range=400&</b>stringandsoon...
```

I successfully matched the "range=100"-part with

> alert( string.match(/range=100/) );

But when I try to replace it,

> string.replace(/range=100/, 'range=400');

nothing happens. The string still has the range=100 in it. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `replace` does not modify the string it is applied on, but returns a new string.

```
string = string.replace(/range=100/, 'range=400');
```

Answer (score 6):

string.replace isn't destructive, meaning, it doesn't change the instance it is called on.

To do this use

```
string = string.replace("range=100","range=400");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
string.replace(/([?&])range=100(?=&|$)/, '$1range=400')
```

This will only replace `range=100` if it’s a URI argument (so it’s delimited on the left by either `?` or `&` and on the right by `&` or the end of the string).

Comment: This is the most useful answer imho

Answer (score 1):

Write only `string.replace("range=100","range=400");`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way

```
string = string.replace(/\brange=100(?!\d)/, 'range=400');
```