# Search and replace specific query string parameter value in javascript

Tags: javascript, search, replace, design-patterns, match

I have a string which is something like this :

```
a_href= "www.google.com/test_ref=abc";
```

I need to search for test_ref=abc in thisabove strinng and replace it with new value

```
var updated_test_ref = "xyz";

a_href ="www.google.com/test_ref=updated_test_ref"
```

i.e

```
www.google.com/test_ref=xyz.
```

How can we do this ?

EDIT:

test_ref value can be a URL link in itself something like http://google.com?param1=test1&param2=test2. I need to capture complete value not till first &.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing strings with regex in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801970/replacing-strings-with-regex-in-javascript)

Comment: This question has been asked a million times. Did you try searching first?

Comment: no .. its similar but not duplicate. I dont know the value of test_ref ..as its a query string parameter it value changes with different pages.Also i need to replace the value with value of variable updated_test_ref. Its not a fix value.I first need to capture everything following test_ref something like this string.replace(/test_ref=(.*)?/ ) and then just replace the matching part with updated_test_ref value.

Comment: Hi Jon.. yes.. I did but i was unable to get what I am looking for in particular.

Comment: @Jon - See my title update. In light of that and @cwolves's answer, this is not simply a dup of your link (though it might be a dup of something else (haven't looked))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
a_href = a_href.replace(/(test_ref=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + updated_test_ref);
```

Comment: Explanation: literally match the string "test_ref=", followed by one or more things that are not the query string parameter separator ("&"), and replace with the captured match ("test_ref="), followed by the value of the variable `updated_test_ref`.

Comment: what happens if my initial test_ref value is something like this = "http://www.google.com?ie=UTF8&param1=test1&param2=test2" . please note that test_ref value is also a URL link in itself. I need to capture complete value of test_ref not till first &

Comment: @TopCoder - This is the type of question that doesn't need to be asked. Just get Firebug and test it in the console yourself. "What happens if...?" is almost never a good question. Just try it.

Comment: Actually, I think a better approach would be to use /([?|&]test_ref=)[^\&]+/ as you can have another parameter which ends with test_ref

Comment: hi to make it better, how do we make the regular expression case insensitive? @lwburk

Comment: Simply add the *ignorecase* (`i`) flag to the end of the regex, like this: `/(test_ref=)[^\&]+/i`

Answer (score 4):

Based on this discussion I have fixed the Chris function (problem with regex string!)

```
function updateUrlParameter(url, param, value){
    var regex = new RegExp('('+param+'=)[^\&]+');
    return url.replace( regex , '$1' + value);
}
```

Comment: Your 2 last comments were just rewriting an accepted answer... Please answer a solved problem only if you have more information to provide than the accepted one. If not, just upvote the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this discussion I have created a references function. enjoy

```
updateUrlParameter(url, param, value){
    var regex = new RegExp("/([?|&]" + param + "=)[^\&]+/");
    return url.replace(regex, '$1' + value);
}
```

Comment: I had a hard time getting this to work until I realized that you need to remove the leading and ending forward slashes. These are assumed to be there automatically, I guess, and end up doubled if you put them into your string.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this solution for few hours and finally stumbled upon this question. I have tried all the solutions here. But there is still an issue while replacing specific param value in url.
Lets take a sample url like

`http://google.com?param1=test1&param2=test2&anotherparam1=test3`

and the updated url should be like

`http://google.com?param1=newtest&param2=test2&anotherparam1=test3`, where value of `param1` is changed.

In this case, as @[Panthro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656094/panthro) has pointed out, adding `[?|&]` before the querying string ensures that `anotherparam1` is not replaced. But this solution also adds the '?' or '&' character to the matching string. So while replacing the matched characters, the '?' or '&' will also get replaced. You will not know exactly which character is replaced so you cannot append that character as well.

The solution is to match '?' or '&' as preceding characters only.

I have re-written the function of @[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047845/chris), fixing the issue with string and have added case insensitive argument.

```
updateUrlParameter(url, param, value){
    var regex = new RegExp('(?<=[?|&])(' + param + '=)[^\&]+', 'i');
    // return url.replace(regex, param + '=$1' + value);
    return url.replace(regex, param + '=' + value);
}
```

Here `(?<=[?|&])` means, the regex will match '?' or '&' char and will take the string that occurs after the specified character (looks behind the character). That means only `param1=test1` substring will be matched and replaced.

Comment: garbage code. 
updateUrlParameter("/fileserver.aspx?mid=1&t=SGK&id=0&f=File2&p=w","id","23954");
returns "/fileserver.aspx?mid=1&t=SGK&id=id=23954&f=File2&p=w"

Comment: Have updated a small mistake in this line
`return url.replace(regex, param + '=$1' + value);`

I haven't noticed before. thanks for pointing out. The correction will be 
`return url.replace(regex, param + '=' + value);`

Comment: **Positive lookbehind** i.e. `?<=` is not supported by many browsers. Alternative is to use **word boundary** i.e. `\b`. Example `queryString.replace(/\bsource=[^&]+/, 'source=' + value)`, where `source` is the parameter-name we are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit dirty code but I've achieved what I was looking for. It replaces the given query string or adds new one if it doesn't exist yet.

```
function updateUrlParameter(url, param, value) {

    var index = url.indexOf("?");

    if (index > 0) {

        var u = url.substring(index + 1).split("&");

        var params = new Array(u.length);

        var p;
        var found = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
            params[i] = u[i].split("=");
            if (params[i][0] === param) {
                params[i][1] = value;
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            params.push(new Array(2));
            params[params.length - 1][0] = param;
            params[params.length - 1][1] = value;
        }

        var res = url.substring(0, index + 1) + params[0][0] + "=" + params[0][1];
        for (var i = 1; i < params.length; i++) {
            res += "&" + params[i][0] + "=" + params[i][1];
        }
        return res;

    } else {
        return url + "?" + param + "=" + value;
    }

}
```

It will work when given regular URL addresses like:

```
updateUrlParameter('https://www.example.com/some.aspx?mid=1&id=2','id','5');
updateUrlParameter('https://www.example.com/?mid=1&id=2','id','5');
updateUrlParameter('https://www.example.com/some.aspx','id','5');
```

**Please note** It will NOT work only if any of the query string parameter name or value contains "=" and/or "&" chars. It will work just fine behind that.

Answer (score -1):

**Java script code to find a specific query string and replace its value  **

```
('input.letter').click(function () {
                //0- prepare values
                var qsTargeted = 'letter=' + this.value; //"letter=A";
                var windowUrl = '';
                var qskey = qsTargeted.split('=')[0];
                var qsvalue = qsTargeted.split('=')[1];
                //1- get row url
                var originalURL = window.location.href;
                //2- get query string part, and url
                if (originalURL.split('?').length > 1) //qs is exists
                {
                    windowUrl = originalURL.split('?')[0];
                    var qs = originalURL.split('?')[1];
                    //3- get list of query strings
                    var qsArray = qs.split('&');
                    var flag = false;
                    //4- try to find query string key
                    for (var i = 0; i < qsArray.length; i++) {
                        if (qsArray[i].split('=').length > 0) {
                            if (qskey == qsArray[i].split('=')[0]) {
                                //exists key
                                qsArray[i] = qskey + '=' + qsvalue;
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!flag)//   //5- if exists modify,else add
                    {
                        qsArray.push(qsTargeted);
                    }
                    var finalQs = qsArray.join('&');
                    //6- prepare final url
                    window.location = windowUrl + '?' + finalQs;
                }
                else {
                    //6- prepare final url
                    //add query string
                    window.location = originalURL + '?' + qsTargeted;
                }
            })
        });
```