# Javascript: split and replace url

Tags: javascript

`http://127.0.0.1:8890/demo1/?search=hello%2Cbuddy&Agg=Target+-+All`

How do I split the above url and fetch 'search=hello%2Cbuddy' and replace the url as `http://127.0.0.1:8890/demo1/?search=goodbye&Agg=Target+-+All`

Using javascript I've only reached this far;

```
var get_url = window.location.href
var parts = get_url.split('/') # doesn't make sense
```

Comment: What exactly did not work for you referencing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413899/search-and-replace-specific-query-string-parameter-value-in-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801970/replacing-strings-with-regex-in-javascript ?

Comment: `get_url.replace('hello%2Cbuddy','goodbye')`

Comment: @AmitGarg I guess the actual searchstring is unknown so a direct replacement would not work here

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can replace this part with a simple regular expression:

```
var url          = document.location.href,
    modified_url = url.replace(/\?search=[^&]+/g, 'search=YOUR_SEARCH_REPLACEMENT');
```

Replace YOUR_SEARCH_REPLACEMENT with whatever you need there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this function may be best for you?

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/2992661

Possibly a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery URL plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/url/) if you're familiar with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the Query String, which this post covers: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Then you just need to update the url by changing `location.href` to whatever you want the URL to be.